# How do I make notifications for removable media hotplug to be temporary

Tags: gnome3, notifications

In Gnome 3.16, when you connect a USB disk a notification pops up **and stays** until you dismiss it.

This is annoying since the notification bubble is right in the top centre of the screen.

I would like this type of notification to be like other notifications, that is, it appears for a few seconds, then disappears. How do I do this?